# Process Builder to Send emails based on Date Field

Tags: email, process-builder

I have a custom object that has a Due Date field that I want to fire off emails 21/14/7 days in advance notifying the owner that the record is almost overdue.
I have used Process Builder that sends emails at these particular timed intervals but *it also fires off an email when the record is updated*.

How do I send an email 21/14/7 days prior to the Due Date that only reevaluates the Scheduled Action when the Due Date is edited and not when the record is edited. (The Due Date is likely to be changed occasionally)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute action only when the Due Date is edited, select "Formula evaluates to true" for Criteria for Executing Actions* and the formula should be something like-

```
(ISCHANGED([Loan_stock__c].Due_date__c) && !ISNEW() //if its not a new record
||
ISNEW())
```

Include other criteria's as well(which you have mentioned above in question) in above formula as per your requirement.

Comment: This is great thanks.  I've done some testing and I notice that this will only send an email if the due date is changed.  how do i get it to include when only the due date is created and also when it is changed.  Here is my formula: (ISCHANGED([Loan_Stock__c].Due_date__c) && !ISNEW()
&& 
ISPICKVAL([Loan_Stock__c].Current_status__c, "Active"))